# error while multiply matrix and vector with GLM

Tags: opengl, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication, glm-math

i get this error while trying multiply matrix and vector with GLM following this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

```
reading1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
reading1.cpp:50:44: error: conversion from ‘glm::detail::tmat4x4<int>’ to non-scalar type ‘glm::mat4 {aka glm::detail::tmat4x4<float>}’ requested
```

I am using this command to compiling.

g++ 1.cpp -o 1 -lGLEW -lglfw

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

//program



glm::mat4 myMatrix = glm::translate(10,0,0);
glm::vec4 myVector(10,10,10,0);
glm::vec4 transformedVector = myMatrix * myVector;

//program
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found GLM to be very picky about types due to the heavy use of templates. My guess is that either your vec4 or mat4 are creating `int` types, and not `float`.

Try creating them with floats explicitly, as it won't autoconvert them if there are int constuctors available that match the template.

```
glm::mat4 myMatrix = glm::translate(10.f,0.f,0.f);
glm::vec4 myVector(10.f,10.f,10.f,0.f);
```

Comment: Thanks for help! i am n00b on openGL you have saved me.